# cannot change wine resolution

Tags: wine, resolution

i have gotten wine in a certain small resolution  so when i try to fix it the window is too small to click the "apply changes" box in the configuration window. HELP! [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDDSm.png "tooltip"

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the `Tab` key to navigate the window. The `Ok` button is the one that comes after the dpi field. Once you think you have selected the `Ok` button, you should be able to use `Space` or `Enter` to confirm your selection.